# Thread-safety of xll functions

Tags: c++, excel, multithreading, thread-safety, xll

I have this stupid xll function :

```
__declspec(dllexport) long F(long arg1, long arg2)
{
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

I guess there's no problem with it, the resulting excel function will be thread-safe.

But what about a function taking arrays and returning arrays ? Consider for instance the function :

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI G(LPXLOPER12 arrayin1, LPXLOPER12 arrayin2)
{
    static XLOPER12 xlArray; // the reference to this one is going to be returned
    // treating arrayin1 and arrayin2 and outputting something in xlArray
    return static_cast<LPXLOPER12>(&xlArray);
}
```

Obviously the `static` is bad for thread-safety and concurrent call in excel. How should I modify my function to ensure thread-safety ?

**EDIT**

Example of code using handles :

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI CreateComplex(LPXLOPER12 arrayin1, LPXLOPER12 arrayin2)
{
    static XLOPER12 xlArray;
    xlArray.xltype = xltypeStr;
    if (arrayin1->xltype != xltypeNum)
    {
        xlArray.val.str = L"blah";
        return static_cast<LPXLOPER12>(&xlArray);
    }
    if (arrayin2->xltype != xltypeNum)
    {
        xlArray.val.str = L"blahblah";
        return static_cast<LPXLOPER12>(&xlArray);
    }
    double real = arrayin1->val.num;
    double imag = arrayin2->val.num;
    Complex * z = new Complex(real, imag);
    char * handle = StoreObject("Complex", z);
    xlArray.xltype = xltypeStr;
    FromCharPtrToWChartPtr(handle, &xlArray.val.str);
    return static_cast<LPXLOPER12>(&xlArray);
}

__declspec(dllexport) double WINAPI GetComplexNorm(LPXLOPER12 arrayin)
{
    char *handle = nullptr;
    FromWChartPtrToWharPtr(arrayin->val.str, &handle);
    Complex * z = (Complex*)RetrieveObject(handle);
    double res = z->getNorm();
    return res;
}
```

`Complex` being a classic complex numbers class, and the "memory" functions being as follows (beware it's old C code) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "memory.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "XLCALL.H"
#include <cstdlib>

void FromCharPtrToWChartPtr(char * from, XCHAR **to)
{
    size_t len = strlen(from);
    *to = new XCHAR[len + 1];
    *to[0] = static_cast<XCHAR>(len);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        mbstowcs(*to + 1, from, len + 1);
    }
}

void FromWChartPtrToWharPtr(XCHAR * from, char **to)
{
    size_t len = from[0];
    *to = new char[len + 1];
    wcstombs(*to, from + 1, len);
}

typedef struct _TObject
{
    char *name;
    int   version; /* increments by 1 for every new store operation */
    void *data;
    void *next;
} TObject;


static TObject *cache = NULL;

#define SEPARATOR '#'

TObject* FindNode(char* name)
{
    TObject *node = cache;
    while (node)
    {
        if (_stricmp(node->name, name) == 0)
            break;

        node = (TObject*)node->next;
    }

    return node;
}

#define FAILURE -1
#define SUCCESS 0

char* StoreObject(char* name, void* data)
{
    static char *routine = "StoreObject";
    int          status = FAILURE;
    char        *handle = NULL;
    TObject     *node;

    static char buffer[255];

    if (data == NULL)
    {
        // error to handle later
        goto done;
    }

    if (name == NULL)
    {
        // error to handle later
        goto done;
    }

    if (strlen(name) > 200)
    {
        // error to handle later
        goto done;
    }

    node = FindNode(name);
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        node = new TObject();
        if (node == NULL)
            goto done;

        node->name = _strdup(name);
        node->version = 1;
        node->data = data;
        node->next = cache;
        cache = node;
    }
    else
    {
        node->version += 1;
        delete node->data; // should I template taylor the object destruction diffenrently ?
        node->data = data;
    }

    sprintf(buffer, "%s%c%d\0", node->name, SEPARATOR, node->version);
    handle = _strdup(buffer);
    if (handle == NULL)
        goto done;

    strcpy(handle, buffer);
    status = SUCCESS;

done:
    if (status != SUCCESS)
    {
        // error to handle later
        delete handle;
        handle = NULL;
    }

    return handle;
}

void* RetrieveObject(char* handle)
{
    static char *routine = "RetrieveObject";
    int          status = FAILURE;
    void        *data = NULL;
    char        *name = NULL;
    TObject     *node;
    char        *sep;

    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        // error to handle later
        goto done;
    }

    name = _strdup(handle);
    if (name == NULL)
        goto done;

    /* remove version number from lookup string */
    sep = strchr(name, SEPARATOR);
    if (sep != NULL)
        *sep = '\0';

    node = FindNode(name);
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        // error to handle later
        goto done;
    }

    data = node->data;
    status = SUCCESS;

done:
    if (status != SUCCESS)
    {
        // error to handle later
        data = NULL;
    }

    delete name;
    return data;
}

void FreeObjects()
{
    TObject *next = cache;
    TObject *node;

    while (next)
    {
        node = next;
        next = (TObject*)node->next;
        delete node->name;
        delete node->data;
        delete node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it non static and allocate memory?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good presentation on [this MSN webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687868(v=office.15).aspx), indeed static is not thread safe, you need to allocate the new variable to a thread local safe memory. You can have a look to the function `get_thread_local_xloper12` in the aforementioned page.

Comment: Thx, I will have a look and validate your answer after. Strange that on the link code is said to be c# but is vanilla c++.

Comment: Remark : I am used to implement functions returning "handles", and function taking "handles" as parameters, handles being label to object in memory. Do you think that framework is well disposed for multi-threading ? I will post code later tonight

Comment: Yes if the associated memory and code is itself thread-safe (lock with critical section) but It can be difficult to implement, be careful to deadlocks. In your case I would prefer to mark functions as being no-thread safe, in order to avoid all the potential problems with handles...

Comment: Your cache is not thread safe, you need to protect each operations ( Find, Retrieve, Free ...) with locks to prevent that several threads modify the state of the cache simultaneously.

Comment: Ok thx, I never really learned to write thread-safe code, guess I'll have to

Comment: So basically I just have to define a `static std::mutex mutx;` outside the functions, and wrap all functions' body codes between `mutx.lock();` and `mutx.unlock()` and that's it ?

Comment: Can't I after do the same for the xll function (modulo a switch to non static arrays declarations) ? (Therefore not having to resort to the msdn link you pointes me to.)

Comment: My mistake, no it is not possible because each time excel call your xll, it has to copy the return variable internally. If its locked by another process I think it will crash.

Comment: So protecting my memory functions isn't possible per se ?

Comment: Last comment, you have to protect all operations related to the static cache, and you can't protect the return variable in the same way, you need to use a thread local memory for the return variable as I said in my answer.